# TypeScript module for testing in node and running on web

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module

I'm been learning TypeScript / ES6, and although I have a bit of "old school" experience with JavaScript from a few years ago, I'm now getting really confused with how modules work!

My mini project structure:

- `convert.ts` contains a simple text converter function that I'm working on: `convert()`.
- `index.ts` is a testing file to run in node. It basically just does:

  ```
  import fs = require('fs');
  import {convert} from "./convert"

  let textToConvert = fs.readFileSync("myTestFile.txt", "utf8");
  console.log(convert(textToConvert));
  ```

However, after finishing testing, I'd like to put out `convert.js` in a form that I can load up in an HTML file, and allow the user to paste in some text or load up a file for conversion in the browser.

I'm confused about how I should have all my config files set up for working on VSCode to do the **simplest possible** setup for this scenario including how the modules should work. So, how should my:

- tsconfig.json
- package.json
- .vscode/launch.json

...be set up? I'm not interested in adding any kind of complex build tools, just the very basics please!

If there's even a simple way to do it without modules at all that would be great too!

Comment: The question is too broad in its current state. If you're using modules (imports and exports), you should use either build tool (Webpack) or native modules which have experimental support in browsers. If you're not interested in build tools and want to use it in real application with good browser support, you're running out of options.

Comment: Oh okay! I thought it would be a straightforward thing, if that's just not an easy thing to do, then fair enough.

Comment: You can also try `System` (SystemJS) or `AMD` (require.js) modules for less efficient setup that doesn't require a build step, see `module` option https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html . But I'd suggest to learn how things are done with Webpack if you're interested in learning current industry standards. There's a bunch of TS+Webpack boilerplate/starter kits on Github that do that for you.

Comment: Yes, actually webpack looks like it might be the thing to do, and can potentially be quite simple/minimal since my use case is basically their "hello world"!